# If I buy a PS3 game second hand, will I still get all the content?

Tags: ps3

A friend of mine is considering [Assassins Creed: Revelations, collectors edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed:_Revelations#Retail_editions) and they arew worried that as it's pre-owned that they won't be able to access all the content, both stuff *in the box* such as the multiplayer character that might have to be activated, and downloadable content, that might require a certain login.

I know I've been stuck before by this sort of issue and I wanted to find out if there was a risk of this sort of thing happening here.

**Will all the content of a pre-owned PS3 game be available to the new owner? And where can I research this sort of information for myself in the future?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only have access to what is on the disk. If the previous owner has purchased any DLC then it will only be available on his/her account. Everything that has been purchased from the PlayStation Store will only be available on the account which has been used to purchase it.

An example:

I have `Mortal Kombat` with some DLCs for it. If I'll lend/sell my disk to anyone, he will only have basic `Mortal Kombat`, no DLCs.

But `Mortal Kombat` requires a key to play online. If I already activated that key, nobody else will be able to use it, so they will have to purchase the key online.

Answer (score 4):

Anything that was on the disc when the original owner bought it should still be there. Also, downloadable content is specific to one account. If the multiplayer character is a purchase code and has been used, it can't be used again sadly.

Comment: Thanks very much, is this from personal experience or something you've read somewhere?

Comment: it's not from my own personal experience, but from a friend's.

Comment: I foudn this: http://ubisoft.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15731/~/how-do-i-activate-uplay-passport%3F could I buy a replacement code?

Comment: I'm not too sure on that one, might be worth seeing if someone replies here or you might want to contact Ubisoft Support.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't.

I bought mine pre owned and it didn't let me download the DLC's